# Magento 1.9 admin grid custom report displays same collection data in all rows

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, reports

I am developing a customised grid report which gives result as per the given time period for specific order status. As a result I am getting same collection in all rows instead of getting a result according to the relevant date.
[image]

Can someone please help me fix this asap.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @Pratik, welcome! "I am developing [...]" implies that there is custom code written by you - without showing what you did so far it will be near to impossible for almost everybody to help you out. Please see the relevant help article on this topic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hello @ChristophFarnleitner,

Thanks for your comment. Actually there is nothing new in my code. It's basic which we are using to build custom admin report. Sorry to say that I won't be able to share code. Do you have any general idea what should be the reason of getting same result in all rows instead of getting result in specific row on respective created at date. That would be really great help.

Comment: what is the result of the `echo $collection->getSelect()` ? is it a valid query string for your needs . DId you check that ?